# StatusBar Background Black, UIAlertView Background Black, everything is Black

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, statusbar

I have a project with a `UINavigationController` as a root view controller. The deployment target is iOS 7 though I upgraded the project from iOS 6.

[image: Black Status Bar]

Now when I change the `barStyle` of my `UINavigationBar` to `UIBarStyleBlack` my status bar becomes black. Just completely black, no content behind it. I also can't control the status bar style using `preferredStatusBarStyle` or `preferesStatusBarHidden` as I do in other projects.

I searched the whole project directory for "statusbar" – nothing. I threw out every pod that might manipulate the `statusBar` – nothing. I compared my `Info.plist` to the one of an iOS 7 control project where everything is find – nothing. What could it be?!

Also many other elements have a completly black background like UIAlertViews.

[image: UIAlertViews]

Comment: Are you by any chance manipulating the appearance of UI elements using appearance proxies (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: No, I did not. But I think I found the solution.

Comment: Would have been an important indicator that you are using external screens :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both problems have the same reason: External Screens.

- the Black Background problem exists only in the Simulator. [UIColor clearColor] suddenly seems to become black. I did not find out why this happens or how to solve it.
- The status bar problem manifests after connecting an external screen. I solved it by calling [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible] after creating the window for the external screen again. The same seems to be necessary after the screen is disconnected.